# How to read text (Definition) of a Stored Procedure in JDBC Code

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, teradata

Executing "SHOW PROCEDURE STORE_PROCEDURE_NAME" return full definition in SQL assistant but when we execute using JDBC it returns only a starting part of SP >> "REPLACE PROCEDURE DATABASENAME."

```
String getviewDDL = "SHOW PROCEDURE STORE_PROCEDURE_NAME";
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(getviewDDL);
        while (rs.next()) { 
            ddlString = rs.getString(1).trim();
        }
```

Comment: Which database system are you using? JDBC doesn't provide anything for this, so you would need to use a database-specific solution.

Comment: Database Name - Teradata

Comment: I'm not a Java guy, but this shows a working example for SHOW: https://downloads.teradata.com/extensibility/articles/running-unsupported-queries-from-a-stored-procedure